# pip installation error for tensorflow

Tags: python-2.7, ubuntu, tensorflow

I was trying to install tensorflow from source on ubuntu 14.04, python 2.7.
I followed the steps from "tensorflow.org" for source installation.
I had completed all the steps, such as bazel installation, python dependencies installation.
In the final step for sudo pip installation; the command was as follows:-

```
$sudo pip install /tmp/tensorflow_pkg/tensorflow-1.3.0rc0-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl
```

but i am getting error as follows:

```
Unpacking /tmp/tensorflow_pkg/tensorflow-1.3.0rc0-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl
Downloading/unpacking tensorflow-tensorboard (from tensorflow==1.3.0rc0)
  Cannot fetch index base URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement tensorflow-tensorboard (from tensorflow==1.3.0rc0)
Cleaning up...
No distributions at all found for tensorflow-tensorboard (from tensorflow==1.3.0rc0)
Storing debug log for failure in /home/ubuntu/.pip/pip.log
```

i also checked tensorflow_pkg wheel :but the above package was not available there.
so  can a different .whl can be insatlled using pip such as -tensorflow-1.2.1-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl 
which have downloaded in my desktop.

Please tell me how i can resolve this issue.

Thanks and regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue was resolved by following steps.

I updated the pip using 

Also exported proxy settings.
e.g export https_proxy=...

This was able to resolve my issue.

I also tried installing other .whl file for tensorflow and yes tensorflow can be installed using the downloaded .whl file also.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I didn't figure out the root of the problem, but for what its worth I skipped the tensorboard issue by installing an older version (1.2.0 worked for me)

```
pip install https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow-1.2.0-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
pip install tensorflow
```

If that doesn't work:

```
sudo pip  install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow-1.2.1-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl
```

[More info here](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_linux#InstallingNativePip) and [Common problems here](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_linux#common_installation_problems).